# Dynamic content to uiscrollview with autolayout not working as expected

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to add dynamic content to the scrollview as below

```
 for i in 0 ..< 4 {
            let gameView = Card.instantiate()
            gameView.frame.origin.y  =  gameView.frame.size.height * CGFloat(i)
            contentView.addSubview(gameView)
            gameView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gameView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,toItem: contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.8,constant : 0.0)

         contentView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

         let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gameView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)

         gameView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)


         contentView.frame.size.height = contentView.frame.size.height + gameView.frame.size.height

         scrollView.contentSize.height = scrollView.contentSize.height + gameView.frame.size.height
        }
```

Cardview is defined xib with autolayout
[image]

And view structure in IB as below SuperView > ScrollView > ContentView > DynamicViews

ContentView Also contain some static contents like buttons and labels.Dynamic View is below that static contents

[image]

And the output screen is look like below but which is not proper-aligned[image]

Is this the correct approach to add dynamic views to scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal case for `UIStackView`

The stack view will handle vertical positioning and width of the instantiated `gameView`s (assuming you have your xib loading set up correctly).

By constraining the top, leading, trailing, bottom and width of the stack view to the scrollView, it will also define the "scrollable area" (the `.contentSize`).

All done with auto-layout:

```
    let sv = UIStackView()
    sv.axis = .vertical
    sv.alignment = .fill
    sv.distribution = .fill
    sv.spacing = 0  // change to add vertical spacing if desired
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(sv)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
        sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
        sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
        sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
        sv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
        ])
    for _ in 0 ..< 4 {
        let gameView = Card.instantiate()
        gameView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        gameView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        sv.addArrangedSubview(gameView)
    }
```

Comment: I have some buttons and content above the dynamic data. In this case Is uistackview works perfectly ? is the contentsize increases automatically?

Comment: Of course... You can either constrain the top of the stack view below your other buttons and content, or also put those elements in the stack view.